# The tag 'img' may only appear as a descendant of tag 'noscript'. Did you mean 'amp-img'?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html amp lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <title>Reliant Industrial Supply</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link
      rel="canonical"
      href="https://http://www.reliantindustrialsupply.com/"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,600"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sora:wght@200&display=swap"
    />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1"
    />
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "NewsArticle",
        "headline": "Open-source framework for publishing content",
        "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
        "image": ["logo.jpg"]
      }
    </script>
    <style amp-boilerplate>
      body {
        -webkit-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
        -moz-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
        -ms-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
        animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
      @-moz-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
      @-ms-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
      @-o-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
      @keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <noscript
      ><style amp-boilerplate>
        body {
          -webkit-animation: none;
          -moz-animation: none;
          -ms-animation: none;
          animation: none;
        }
      </style></noscript
    >

    <style amp-custom>
      :root {
        --background: rgba(299, 299, 299, 0.95);
      }

      *,
      *::before,
      *::after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: "Work Sans";
      }

      /* navigation styles start here */

      .header {
        background: var(--background);
        text-align: center;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 999;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .nav-toggle {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
      }

      .nav-toggle:focus ~ .nav-toggle-label {
        outline: 3px solid rgba(lightblue, 0.75);
      }

      .nav-toggle-label {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 1em;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .nav-toggle-label span,
      .nav-toggle-label span::before,
      .nav-toggle-label span::after {
        display: block;
        background: black;
        height: 2px;
        width: 2em;
        border-radius: 2px;
        position: relative;
      }

      .nav-toggle-label span::before,
      .nav-toggle-label span::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
      }

      .nav-toggle-label span::before {
        bottom: 7px;
      }

      .nav-toggle-label span::after {
        top: 7px;
      }

      nav {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: left;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        background: var(--background);
        width: 100%;
        transform: scale(1, 0);
        transform-origin: top;
        transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
      }

      nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
      }

      nav li {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        margin-left: 1em;
      }

      nav a {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
      }

      nav a:hover {
        color: #000;
      }

      .nav-toggle:checked ~ nav {
        transform: scale(1, 1);
      }

      .nav-toggle:checked ~ nav a {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
      }

      amp-carousel {
        padding-top: 20em;
      }

      @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
        .nav-toggle-label {
          display: none;
        }

        .header {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr auto minmax(600px, 3fr) 1fr;
        }

        .logo {
          grid-column: 2 / 3;
        }

        nav {
          position: relative;
          text-align: left;
          transition: none;
          transform: scale(1, 1);
          background: none;
          top: initial;
          left: initial;

          grid-column: 3 / 4;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: flex-end;
          align-items: center;
        }

        nav ul {
          display: flex;
        }

        nav li {
          margin-left: 3em;
          margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        nav a {
          opacity: 1;
          position: relative;
        }

        nav a::before {
          content: "";
          display: block;
          height: 5px;
          background: black;
          position: absolute;
          top: -0.75em;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          transform: scale(0, 1);
          transition: transform ease-in-out 250ms;
        }

        nav a:hover::before {
          transform: scale(1, 1);
        }
      }

      amp-carousel {
        top: 0em;
        padding-bottom: 5em;
      }

      .content {
        background-color: dark-grey;
      }
      .Centered {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "Work Sans";
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 300;
        padding-bottom: 2em;
      }

      .left {
        margin: 2rem;
        font-family: 'Sora', sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      .clearfix {
        overflow: auto;
        display: flex;
        padding-bottom: 5em;
      }

      .footer {
          width: 100vw;
          display: block;
          overflow: hidden;
          padding: 20px 0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          background-color: #18181a;
      }

      .innerFooter {
          display: block;
          margin: 0 auto;
          width: 1100px;
          height: 100%;
      }

      .innerFooter .logoContainer {
        width: 35%;
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
      }

      .innerFooter .footerThird {
        padding-left: 20px;
        width: calc(21.66666667 - 20px);
        margin-right: 10px;
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .innerFooter .footerThird:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;

      }

      .innerFooter .footerThird h1{
        font-family: 'Work Sans';
        font-size: 22px;
        color: white;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      .innerFooter span {
        font-family: 'Work Sans';
        font-size: 12px;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>

    <script
      async
      custom-element="amp-carousel"
      src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.2.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      async
      custom-element="amp-video"
      src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-video-0.1.js"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="header">
    <amp-img
    src="https://i.imgur.com/vPr7fdQ.png"
    width="175px"
    height="50px"
    ></amp-img>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle" />
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a
            href="file:///C:/Users/pilot/Documents/GitHub/AMP/Home/Home-Page.html"
            >Home</a
          >
        </li>
        <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/pilot/Documents/GitHub/AMP/Products/products_page.html">Products</a></li>
        <li>
          <a
            href="file:///C:/Users/pilot/Documents/GitHub/AMP/Contact/Contact.html"
            >Contact</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>


    <amp-carousel
      layout="fixed-height"
      type="slides"
      height="900"
      width="auto"
      controls
      loop
      autoplay
      delay="3000"
      data-next-button-aria-label="Go to next slide"
      data-previous-button-aria-label="Go to previous slide"
    >
      <amp-img
        src="https://i.imgur.com/6H2AFQm.png"
        width="1280"
        height="720"
      ></amp-img>
      <amp-img
        src="https://i.imgur.com/6jOfwYY.png"
        width="1280"
        height="720"
      ></amp-img>
      <amp-img
        src="https://i.imgur.com/AFq0mSz.png"
        width="1280"
        height="720"
      ></amp-img>
      <amp-img
        src="https://i.imgur.com/7tMi95w.png"
        width="1280"
        height="720"
      ></amp-img>
      <amp-img
        src="https://i.imgur.com/G020qk3.png"
        width="1280"
        height="720"
      ></amp-img>
      <amp-video
        layout="fixed"
        autoplay
        loop
        width="1280"
        height="720"
        poster="https://i.imgur.com/lNFDJb1.png"
      >
        <source src="https://i.imgur.com/3TFahoU.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <div fallback>
          <p>This browser does not support this video element.</p>
        </div>
      </amp-video>
    </amp-carousel>

    <div class="content">
      <h1 class="Centered">
        Providing solutions for all your surface treatments
      </h1>

      <div class="clearfix">
        <div>
          <p class="left">
            Reliant Industrial Supply provides solutions for all your surface
            treatments.Our supplier sia Coated Abrasives, the oldest abrasive
            manufacturer in the world, brings one of the best abrasives on the
            market. We supply Flex Trim brushes for all liner and carousel
            sanding needs. We provide AirVantage Sanders and Coilhose
            Pneumatics, for when you want the best quality handsanding tools and
            results. When it comes to machines, we have one of the best and also
            one of the most experienced machinery manufacturers, Timesavers Wide
            Belt Sanders. For cutting and shaping we have a wide variety of
            Exchangeable Saw Blades and Router Bits. Whether cutting, shaping or
            sanding, you can rely on Reliant. We provide solutions for surface
            preparation through complete sanding systems which include coated
            abrasives, pneumatic sanders and machinery.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <img class="right" src="https://i.imgur.com/u8hDnzX.jpg" layout="responsive" width="800px;" height="300px;"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="innerFooter">
          <div class="logoContainer">
            <amp-img src="https://i.imgur.com/jlRKmij.jpg" height="109" width="200">
          </div>

          <div class="footerThird">
            <h1>Address: 18061 Kirk Ave, Tustin, CA 92780</h1>
            <h1>Phone Number:  (714) 287-6815 </h1>
          </div>

          <div class="footerThird">
            <span>Copyright 2020 Reliant Industrial Supply<span>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you can see on line 469 there is an img there that is not AMP. Obviously you would change that to an amp-img tag and you would be set. While thats not wrong, it does not seem to work properly for me. When I change it in the amp validator to an amp-img, it works. BUT when I run the file to see how it works, it just dissapears and it is really frustrating because I have tried to fix it. The same fix cut and pasted works, then i cut it and paste it again, then it does not work. If someone could figure out why I am having this problem it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Please shorten your example to the minimal version required to reproduced the error. You have posted a huge script that will require copy-pasting to another editor to find out what line 469 is about...

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not know how to to shorten it without leaving out important context.